# Does the equality $\bigcup S(X)=X$ holds for any set $X$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, alternative-proof

We say that a set $X$ is transitive if it is contained into the corresponding power set $\mathscr P(X)$.

Now for $\textbf{any}$ set $X$ let's we put
$$
S(X):=X\cup\{X\}
$$

So if $y$ is in $\bigcup S(X)$ then there exists $Y$ in $S(X)$ such that $y$ is in $Y$ but if $Y$ is in $S(X)$ then it is in $\{X\}$ or in $X$ so that in the first case $y$ is in $X$ whereas in the second it ($y$) is in $X$ provided $X$ is transitive and thus if $X$ is trivially contained into $S(X)$ then into the transitive case we conclude that the equality
$$
\bigcup S(X)=X
\tag{1}
\label{1}
$$
holds. Now my text book into an exercise (clik [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4egu.png) to see it) ask to prove (apparently) that eq. \eqref{1} holds generally but unfortunately I was not able to prove so that I put here a specific question where I ask to prove or disprove if \eqref{1} holds generally. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sorry, but it seems to me I used arbitrary union in my proof attempt: indeed I say that if $y$ is in $\bigcup S(X)$ then there exists $Y$ in $S(X)$ such that $y$ is in $Y$. So could you explain better your hint, please? Forgive my confusion.

Comment: Correct: the result holds for *transitive* sets, i.e. sets such that if $x \in A \in X$, then $x \in X$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Okay, and what can you say about not transitive sets?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  Perfect, I saw: thanks for the counterexample! Obviously if you want post an answer I will surely accept it: thanks yet for the assistance. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concern is correct: the result holds for transitive sets, i.e. sets such that if $x∈A∈X$, then $x∈X$.

For some counterexamples, see Enderton's [Set Theory](https://docs.ufpr.br/%7Ehoefel/ensino/CM304_CompleMat_PE3/livros/Enderton_Elements%20of%20set%20theory_%281977%29.pdf), page 72: consider the set $\{ 0,1,5 \}$.

We have that $4∈5∈ \{ 0,1,5 \}$ but $4∉ \{ 0,1,5 \}$.

Comment: Perfect: answer upvoted and approved. Thanks for it! ;-)

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro - you are welcome :-)